# Searching in Chrome redirects to "find.fnavigate-now.com"

Tags: chrome, windows-10, search-engines

It used to do a Google search. Now it redirects to this weird website, which itself redirects to Yahoo. What gives?

https://find.fnavigate-now.com/results.aspx?q=test&gd=SY1004294&searchsource=58&d=070120&n=9998

Comment: This is most likely a malicious Chrome extension which is redirecting you for financial gain. Check your installed chrome extensions for anything weird or any extensions that you are not directly using. Could be something like ChromeLoader

Comment: @dcom-launch How would I go about removing the infection? I have about 50 Chrome extensions and installing them all one by one would be tedious

Comment: This is just a guess, it may not be the issue at all, this is just similar behavior to malicious chrome extensions. A good place to start would be running a full system scan with antivirus, but it may not be detected. If it was me, I would completely uninstall chrome and reinstall it and only add the few extensions I actually use.

Comment: @dcom-launch I checked my default search engine in Chrome settings, and it was set to Yahoo. But I never set it to that! I changed it back to Google, and the problem disappeared. Hmm. So the virus switched my default search engine, but allows me to change it back? I assume it's still lurking on my system :( Ok. I will do what you've suggested.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30091/best-practices-for-handling-computer-viruses

Comment: Ah, that reminds me of good ol' Internet Explorer troll homepage redirects. Good times. But yeah, nuking it from orbit is the best way to go and also try to keep your extensions list to what you only really require, 50 is an overkill and a resource hog for an already resource hogging browser.